# Hiding an element which is partly or completely hidden by overflow

Tags: html, css

I got a sticky label inside another div. So when I scroll horizontally through the `div`s, the labels stick to the left side of the screen as long as the next `div` comes, which is exactly what I want. Code:

```
.foo-bar-label {
    display: inline-block;
    max-width: 100%;
    left: 0px;
    position: sticky;
    height: 16px;
    overflow: hidden;
  }

.scale-unit {
    border-left: 1px solid black;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 0px 6px;
    height: 16px;
  }
```

Now when I scroll to the right, the leftmost label finally gets overlapped by the left corner, which is the expected behavior.

[image: Before]

[image: After]

(The object to the left, which overlaps the label has the same background, don't mind that.)

Question: How can I, hopefully with pure html / css, prevent the case, that a label is partially hidden, instead it should be completely invisible.

P.S.: A solution would be sufficient, which helps me to hide a `div` completely, IF some of its content overflows!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: give `position:relative` and `z-index` **higher** than the one you want to overlap on `scroll`